# Configure private AudioSession of AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, audio, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

My use-case is the following: I'm trying to add audio recording with AVCaptureSession to an app. The app might play music/sounds and I don't want to change anything about the app's AVAudioSession. I.e. the shared audio session might have a category that's different from PlayAndRecord. So, no problem, I can just set `usesApplicationAudioSession` to false on my AVCaptureSession and it will use a new AudioSession that's distinct from the app's audio session.
However, the documentation states that this

> may cause interruption if your app uses its own audio session for playback.

Which it indeed does. My question is: Is there a way to access the AVCaptureSession's private audio session (and configure it in such a way that it mixes with other audio sources)? Like I said, for this scenario, I don't want to change anything about the configuration of the app's shared audio session.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.